# Spring java Oracle get test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, junit

I try to test my connection to database, when I try to use query in IntelliJ IDEA IDE it works, but unit test failed. I just starting with java, so I probably do something wrong, can you say me how to do it right? I try to test, if I get all values from table Workers and second test is if I get one special value from table Workers.

Worker model class:

```
    package com.bmp.bmp.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKERS")
public class Workers {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "WORKER_ID")
  private int workerId;
  @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
  private String firstname;
  @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
  private String lastname;
  @Column(name = "WORKPLACE_ID")
  private int workplaceId;

  public Workers(int workerId, String firstname, String lastname, int workplaceId)
  {
      super();
      this.workplaceId = workplaceId;
      this.lastname = lastname;
      this.firstname = firstname;
      this.workerId = workerId;
  }
  public Workers()
  {
      super();
  }

  public int getWorkerId() {
    return workerId;
  }

  public void setWorkerId(int workerId) {
    this.workerId = workerId;
  }


  public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
  }

  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }


  public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
  }

  public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }


  public int getWorkplaceId() {
    return workplaceId;
  }

  public void setWorkplaceId(int workplaceId) { this.workplaceId = workplaceId;
  }

}
```

Worker repository class:

```
    package com.bmp.bmp.service.implement;

import com.bmp.bmp.model.Workers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Repository
public class Worker implements com.bmp.bmp.service.interfaces.Worker
{
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Workers workers) {
        String query = "insert into Workers (WORKER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, WORKPLACE_ID) values ((select max(WORKER_ID)+1 from workers),?,?,?); commit;";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try{
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

            ps.setString(1, workers.getFirstname());
            ps.setString(2, workers.getLastname());
            ps.setInt(3, workers.getWorkplaceId());
            int out = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(out !=0){
                System.out.println("Worker saved with id="+workers.getWorkerId());
            }else System.out.println("Worker save failed with id="+workers.getWorkerId());
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Workers getById(int id) {
        String query = "select FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, WORKPLACE_ID from WORKERS where WORKER_ID = ?";
        Workers workers = null;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                workers = new Workers();
                workers.setWorkerId(id);
                workers.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstName"));
                workers.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
                workers.setWorkplaceId(rs.getInt("workplace_id"));
                System.out.println("Worker Found::"+workers);
            }else{
                System.out.println("No worker found with id="+id);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return workers;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Workers workers) {
        String query = "update Workers set FIRSTNAME=?, LASTNAME=?, WORKPLACE_ID=? where WORKER_ID=?; commit;";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try{
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            String firstName = ("'" + workers.getFirstname() + "'");
            String lastName = ("'" + workers.getLastname() + "'");
            ps.setString(1, firstName);
            ps.setString(2, lastName);
            ps.setInt(3, workers.getWorkplaceId());
            ps.setInt(4,workers.getWorkerId());
            int out = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(out !=0){
                System.out.println("Worker updated with id="+workers.getWorkerId());
            }else System.out.println("No worker found with id="+workers.getWorkerId());
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        String query = "delete from WORKERS where WORKER_ID=?; commit;";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try{
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            int out = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(out !=0){
                System.out.println("Worker deleted with id="+id);
            }else System.out.println("No worker found with id="+id);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Workers> getAll() {
        String query = "select WORKER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, WORKPLACE_ID from WORKERS";
        List<Workers> empList = new ArrayList<Workers>();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                Workers workers = new Workers();
                workers.setWorkerId(rs.getInt("worker_id"));
                workers.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
                workers.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
                workers.setWorkplaceId(rs.getInt("workplace_id"));
                empList.add(workers);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return empList;
    }
}
```

Worker unitTest:

```
   package com.bmp.bmp.service.implement;

import com.bmp.bmp.model.Workers;
import com.bmp.bmp.service.interfaces.WorkerInt;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class WorkerTest {
    @Autowired
    Worker worker = new Worker();

    @Test
    public void getAll() {
        List<Workers> workersList = worker.getAll();
        workersList.forEach(System.err::println);
    }

    @Test
    public void getById() {
        Workers workers = worker.getById(7);
    }
}
```

Error message from console

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bmp.bmp.service.implement.WorkerTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'worker'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bmp.bmp.service.implement.Worker' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bmp.bmp.service.implement.Worker' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Is `WorkerTest` configured in any way? From the stacktrace it seems like `worker` field is not initialized. It is null and hence NullPointerException is thrown. Please refer to the following link if you need help with Spring test configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html

Comment: Probably not, this is my first test ever, so there is probably something wrong.

Comment: Why are you `new`ing your autowired field...?

Answer (score 0):

Missing context configuration is causing your worker to not get initialized and therefore causing the null pointer

Replace ContextConfiguration name with actual name and it should get autowired

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/your-spring-context.xml" })
public class WorkerTest {
    @Autowired
    Worker worker;

    @Test
    public void getAll() {
        List<Workers> workersList = worker.getAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void getById() {
        Workers workers = worker.getById(7);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:As suggested that XML file is not being used then only option is that you are using Annotation Based Spring with some YourAppConfiguration.class which has @Configuration

For that we need to change the ContextConfiguration Slightly only

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
   @ContextConfiguration(classes=YourAppConfiguration.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
    public class WorkerTest {
        @Autowired
        Worker worker;

        @Test
        public void getAll() {
            List<Workers> workersList = worker.getAll();
        }

        @Test
        public void getById() {
            Workers workers = worker.getById(7);
        }
    }
```

If still no clear ditch the autowire and use new operator instead

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
        public class WorkerTest {

            Worker worker=new Worker();

            @Test
            public void getAll() {
                List<Workers> workersList = worker.getAll();
            }

                @Test
                public void getById() {
                    Workers workers = worker.getById(7);
                }
            }
```

Comment: is it necessery to use a ContextConfiguration? I asking because, I don' t use any xml

Comment: Are you using a spring annotation based and have @Configuration in some class like App Configuration for autowiring dependencies

Comment: I have made edits to my answer accordingly,please have a look and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Hi, I try it, but still not working.I update code sample and error message. Can you look at it, what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Don' use autowired and new both remove the autowired like my 3rd code